# CAAnimation delegate methods not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, caanimation

I am having an issue with iOS `CABasicAnimation`. No matter what I do, I cannot get the methods `animationDidStart:` and `animationDidStop:finished:` to fire. My class is subclassing `CAShapeLayer` and is performing the animations inside of it:

```
- (void)start{
    [self removeAllAnimations];

    CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [self makeAnimationForKey:@"strokeEnd"];
    [self addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
}

- (CABasicAnimation *)makeAnimationForKey:(NSString *)key {
    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:key];
    anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.f];
    anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.f];

    anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
    anim.duration = self.duration;
    anim.delegate = self;
    return anim;
}

- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)anim{
    NSLog(@"HERE START");
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag{
    NSLog(@"HERE STOP");
}
```

Any tips or help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Remember that layers are cloned when animated, so you may not get the effect you desire using a subclass like this.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder David, I'll be sure to keep it in mind.

Comment: __Be aware that `CAAnimation`'s `delegate` is strong, so you might need to set it to `nil` to avoid retain cycles!__

Answer (score 12):

you must set delegate before assigning animation to layer:

```
popIn.delegate = self;
[annotation.layer addAnimation:popIn forKey:@"popIn"];
```

Swift 5.4.2

```
popIn.delegate = self
annotation.layer.add(transition, forKey:"popIn")
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it turns in my subclass I had a property called duration. Even though it is not documented as being apart of `CALayer`, duration is a part of one of it's protocols called `CAMediaTiming`. The methods were never fired because the property was being overwritten via my subclass.

Comment: That counts as being documented to me. You usually don't mention properties or methods that are declared in protocols that the object conforms to.